# Replace recursively key value pair using jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I have the below json contents in a file one.json.

```
[{
    "session": "One",
    "name": "First Session",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "Session One"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "session": "Two",
    "name": "Second Session",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "Session Two"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to create another json file two.json with the below output

```
[{
    "session": "One",
    "name": "Session One",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "Session One"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "session": "Two",
    "name": "Session Two",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "Session Two"
        }
    ]
}]
```

The difference between file one and file two is the value of "name" is replaced with details[0].name in each instance recursively. Unfortunately I can only use 'jq' to achieve this due to some limitations. I am new to the world of shell script and this one is really bugging me.

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted and which problems you're running into?

Comment: Did you mean "successively" rather than "recursively"?  There is nothing "recursive" about the question as posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map(.name = .details[0].name)
```

1. Map through each object
2. Set `name` key to the `name` of the `0`'st index in `details` array

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "session": "One",
    "name": "Session One",
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "Session One"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "session": "Two",
    "name": "Session Two",
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "Session Two"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### [Jq▶Play](https://jqplay.org/s/sgYYFx8499)

---

To save jq's output to a new json file;

```
jq 'map(.name = .details[0].name)' tst.json > 'newjson.json'
```